# Get my Amazon shopping cart in a ios app,is possible?

Tags: php, ios, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to write an app that show the actual shopping cart of an Amazon account. 
This is the flow: I enter in amazon.com with my browser (login with a normal account,the user will not a seller) ->I choose an item and add it to my shopping cart->close the browser and launch the ios app->Login with my account and retrive the list of all items in my shopping cart,including the last i have just added by browser. 
I have read Product Advertising API Developer Guide (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/ProgrammingGuide.html) , i know that i can manage a remote Cart, what i can't understand is: this remote cart can be syncronized with the normal shopping cart of my amazon account?

Comment: Completely `syncronized`, probably not. Sending a request & retrieving cart contents every ~5 seconds to give the illusion of being syncronized, probably.

Comment: ok and how i can do it, what api i have to use?